# If input have value then run function

Tags: jquery, text, input

if I have this element in my html code

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="city">
```

Why alert doesnt appear if I fill same text into this input?

```
  if ( $("input").val().length > 0) {
    alert("X");
  }
```

Comment: you have to trigger it, try keyup function

Comment: How/when are you trying to run that jQuery?

Comment: You've to watch (listen event) when the value get changed then run your code. Learn about Events in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('input[name="name"]').change(function(){
          if ( $(this).val().length > 0 ){
             //Do something
          }
       });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
   if ($(this).val().length > 0){
      alert('hey');
   }
});
```

Comment: Bare in mind if you want to catch text being entered by a right click then paste or other input methods, you may need to listen for some additional events. e.g. `.on("keyup change mouseup", function(){})`